# Replacement for core service's MPRemoteCall?

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

I have a legacy carbon app that used MPRemoteCall to show an assert dialog when something bad happens on the main thread of the app. Sometimes an assert happens in a worker thread that shouldn't be doing UI stuff. However it's deprecated a long time ago and I was wondering what the replacement API is?

Answer (score 0):

I think [`- [NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414900-performselectoronmainthread) is probably the closest analog to `MPRemoteCall()`.

GCD/blocks should also work:

`dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // do work here
});`

Hopefully these will work correctly if your app is still using a Carbon event loop--I have had problems in the past with Cocoa timer functions in Carbon apps.